# SQL query - How to increase the salary of employees, without exceeding a certain salary limit

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, case

I am trying to get a query that will allow me to increase the salary of people who earn less than 2000, but I don't want the salary increase for these people to be higher than 2000.

The table that I am using is set-up like this:

```
DECLARE @Employee TABLE
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
   ,FirstName NVARCHAR(100)
   ,Surname NVARCHAR(100)
   ,Salary MONEY
) 
INSERT @Employee (FirstName, Surname, Salary) VALUES 
('Michael', 'Barker', 2750), ('Robert', 'Morton', 1550),
('John', 'Mitchell', 1890), ('William', 'Davison', 1840),
('James', 'Houston', 1800), ('Mark', 'Parsons', 2060),
('David', 'Higgins', 1950), ('Richard', 'Frost', 1470),
('Frank', 'Herbert', 2100), ('Brian', 'Matthews', 1930)
```

I am also using a variable for the salary increase, that looks like this:

```
DECLARE @SalaryIncreaseInPercentage DECIMAL(16, 2) = 10
```

The best idea that I could come up with is to use a `CASE` statement. How do i improve the code so the newly increased salary stops at 2000?

The code I wrote to far looks like this:

```
Update @Employee
SET Salary =  CASE
WHEN Salary<2000 THEN((@SalaryIncreaseInPercentage/ 100) * Salary) + Salary
ELSE Salary
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilise `MIN` and `VALUES` functions

```
DECLARE @IncreaseFactor DECIMAL(16, 2) = 10

UPDATE e SET e.Salary = (SELECT MIN(NewSalary) 
    FROM (VALUES (e.Salary * (1 + @IncreaseFactor/100)), (2000)) AS salaries(NewSalary))
FROM @Employee e
WHERE e.Salary < 2000
```

Comment: This worked perfect Fabio. Thank you very much. The only thing I amended is `DECLARE @IncreaseFactor Decimal (16,2) = @SalaryIncreaseInPercentage`, so in case the percentage would be different, the query would still work. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would only modify a little on your original query: you do not want to check if the original salary is under 2000 but if the new salary is under 2000:

```
UPDATE @Employee
SET Salary =  CASE
    WHEN (((@SalaryIncreaseInPercentage / 100) * Salary) + Salary) < 2000 
        THEN ((@SalaryIncreaseInPercentage / 100) * Salary) + Salary
        ELSE WHEN Salary < 2000
            THEN 2000
            ELSE Salary
END
```

Comment: _but I don't want the salary increase for these people to be higher than 2000_ - with this solution some employees will get salary greater than 2000

Comment: This semi works as well. It does what it's supposed to do, but at the same time it also modifies the salaries that are higher than 2000 and sets them as 2000. :( But I will keep this in mind for another situation I might encounter. Thank you ^^

Comment: That's true, my bad

Answer (score 0):

```sql
UPDATE    Employee
SET       Salary =  CASE
WHEN      Salary<2000 THEN((@SalaryIncreaseInPercentage/ 100) * Salary) + Salary
ELSE      Salary
END
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.